# find the count from 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to find this count but when I execute the query it seems like it is stucked to "waiting for the query to complete" forever...any ideas?

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   accidents,"Vechicles"
    where "Date_of_accident"<'2010-01-01' and "Urban_or_Rural" like 'Urban' and "Age_Band_Of_Driver" like '26 - 35'
        ) AS count1
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: ... because the explicit JOIN has an ON clause, so you can't forget the join condition...

Comment: I tried also with inner join syntax but it returned me the count of 0 which is not true..

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Unrelated but `"Urban_or_Rural" like 'Urban' and "Age_Band_Of_Driver" like '26 - 35'` should be `"Urban_or_Rural" = 'Urban' and "Age_Band_Of_Driver" = '26 - 35'`

Answer (score 0):

Because your query will select every row from the first table that matches your criteria, then for each row it will then select EVERY row from the second table that matches your criteria.  This might end up being a huge number of rows that end up selected.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE #dumb (id INT);
CREATE TABLE #dumber (id INT);
INSERT INTO #dumb SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3;
INSERT INTO #dumber SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3;
SELECT * FROM #dumb, #dumber;
```

3 rows in each table, but the query selects 3 * 3 = 9 rows.  Now imagine that there's 3 million rows in each table!

Comment: It won't let me edit the post, so replace # with TEMP and it will work on PostgreSQL.  TBH this doesn't matter anyway, this was just an example to explain why the OPs query takes so long to run.